# After importing react-native-firebase/firestore in to my app, I get the build error 'Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.3.0.'

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have just added [react-native-firebase/firestore](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/firestore/quick-start) v6.2.0 to my React Native app. It was previously building fine whilst using the auth and messaging modules.

Now when I build the app I get the error:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       ...
     Required by:
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_messaging
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_app
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_auth
```

I'm not sure what this file is or why it would have been removed.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

After some tracking I noticed that **com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.3.0** is missing in the
[Maven repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-bom)

Which makes me believe it never existed. After some tracking in the **react-native-firebase** files I noticed that tag **v6.1.0** has **com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.1.0** for some packages except for firestore, which has **com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.3.0**. And this is repeated for **v6.2.0**

So... yeah, It may have been problem updating the dependencies. I may upload an issue to address this.

My solution was to use version **v6.0.3**

You can manually edit the following file in your local **node_modules**: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/v6.1.0/packages/firestore/android/build.gradle